# Rails 3 - belongs_to user AND has_many users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to figure out how to do the following :

a Concert belongs_to a user (the creator), has_many guests and has_many organisers.

Is the following approach is good ?

Concert:

```
 class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :guests, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :organisers, :class_name => 'User'
 end
```

User:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :concerts
 end
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That looks fine. What is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: nice resource here: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/10/30/self-referential-has-many-through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad two new models to hold the has_many relationships:

```
 class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :concert_guests
  has_many   :concert_organizers

  has_many   :guests, :through => :concert_guests, :source => :user
  has_many   :organizers, :through => :concert_organizers, :source => :user
 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :concerts
 end

 # table with user_id and concert_id columns   
 class ConcertGuest
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :concert
 end

 # table with user_id and concert_id columns   
 class ConcertOrganizer
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :concert
 end
```

Comment: Is this the easiest way ? Seems a little bit complicated :)

Comment: If you want to maintain has_many relationship between `User` and `Concert` models this is one of the way to do it.